# Add to array in comma separated values from database

Tags: php, arrays

my database table is named order. it has a row like `order`. I store values like this `1,2,3,4,5`. Now i would like to add to array and from it out info..

I tried to do that but it is not working...

here is my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$sql_order = $row['order'];

$array = array($sql_order);

foreach($array as $x) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = ".$x." LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $sql_order = $row['order'];

    echo $row['product_name'].'<br />';
}
```

if want check `print_r($array)` Output

```
Array ( [0] => 1,23,4,5 )
```

this one is not working.. i think its supposed to be like this: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )`

Comment: Normalize your database, then you also won't run into such problems!

Comment: @Rizier123 i want to out $array like this `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )` help me for this plzz...

Comment: If you normalize your database you won't even have this problem! So normalize your database and don't store multiple data in one field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use explod to split with ","

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $sql_order = $row['order'];

    //$array = array($sql_order);
    $array=explod(",",$sql_order);

    foreach($array as $x) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = ".$x." LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $sql_order = $row['order'];

        echo $row['product_name'].'<br />';
    }
```

Comment: OP wouldn't even have this problem if his database is normalized. And with this you don't solve OP's **real** problem.

Comment: yes, i totally agree with what you say. he need to normalize his database. it's my bad.

Answer (score 2):

### **FASTEST APPROACH**

You need to use `explode()` function. Here is an example of it :

```
<?php
    $array = array('0' =>'1,2,3,4,5');
    $array = explode(',', $array[0]);
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

Here is your updated code, to get array in that format.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$sql_order = $row['order'];

$array = array($sql_order);
$array = explode(',', $array[0]);

foreach($array as $x) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` = ".$x." LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $sql_order = $row['order'];

    echo $row['product_name'].'<br />';
}
```

**Note this is solution which you are looking for. But it isn't recommended due to reason told to you as comment.**

---

### PROPER WAY TO HANDLE THIS

You should ideally normalize your Database so this kind of problem don't come even in future to you.
Here is a proposed table structure change, which you can consider, depending on your need & time.

- Remove `order` column from your table. Add a new table named `order_suborders` as follows:

---

```
|   COLUMN   |    TYPE     | 
|:-----------|------------:|
|parent_order|      int    |     
| order_id   |      int    |
```

*You can change name of columns and table according to your wish.*

- Move old data accordingly.
- Use query `SELECT order_suborders.order_id FROM order, order_suborders WHERE order.id = ".$_GET['id']." AND order.id = order_suborders.parent_order`

Comment: I think this is really misleading, since OP's biggest problem is, that his database is not normalized. And with this he won't solve the problem at the root, he will run into much more and much worse problems if he doesn't normalize it.

Comment: Yes, I know that he hasn't normalized it, added that point too. But this solution is what he is looking for (though not recommended).

Comment: Probably because he don't know how a normalized DB looks like, that's why OP is asking for this.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, ok wait, adding normalization approach too. Though we can't assume ourselves that he need help in normalizing his table, still it might be useful for him. :)